# DIVs Arrangement - HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: Arrangement]

How can i construct above arrangement without using js ?

Thanks in advance !

```
#div3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
#div1 {
    min-width: 150px;
    float: left;
}

#div2 {
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XCDsu/4/ - how can i fit the second div to content ? The first one has to be 150px not percent

Comment: you could use css and html

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: It's quite easy to do in CSS... We are not here to do your homework for you. Please show us what you tried and we'll see if we can help.

Comment: http://learnlayout.com

Comment: Will the `width` of `#div1` change or it's fixed at `150px` ?

Comment: Place `#div1` inside `#div2`

Comment: @NikhilPatel that is minimum width. which is saying that the width can increase more than `150px` but can't decrease below the same value.

Comment: The #div3 width is changing. The width of #div has to be 150px. Ok smarty-pants do it if it's so easy

Comment: @user2587741 to whom you saying that? no one has told you anything rude in the above comments  :/

Comment: All the answer have a problem when column 1 needs to be  bigger than 150px. take a look at mine.

Comment: Mr_Green - sorry about that, english is not my native language, some of my sentences may sound aggressively sometimes ;) I had no intention to be rude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the holy grail technique:
http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail

```
#div3 {
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    padding-left: 150px;
}

#div1 {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -150px;
}

#div2 {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

What this does is create a 150px wide padding on the left of #div3, but it pulls #div1 into it with the negative margin.

This way the "100%" that #div2 uses is actually (100% - 150px) of #div3

Comment: Although your question is a basic layouts 101 issue, that did not make your question invalid. Glad to help, make sure to read and try that holy grail technique until you fully grasp it, it's really a lifesaver (even after all those years).

Answer (score 2):

all of those techniques in the other answers have a common problem.
they are assuming that the `width` of the first column is `150px`, but actually you need `min-width` to be `150px`. so what happens when the first column need to grow?

take a look at my solution. pure CSS, without using `calc` (so its also supported in older browsers like IE8)

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/XCDsu/448/)

**HTML:** nothing new here..

```
<div id="Container">
    <div id="Column1">content</div>
    <div id="Column2">content of second div is very  very large</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#Container
{
    width: 80%; /*Change to WTE you want*/
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#Container > div
{
    display: table-cell;
}
#Column1
{
    background-color: red;
    min-width: 150px; /*From your CSS*/
}

#Column2
{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: I assuming it works too as Stephen answer. I will note that. Thanks for your time ;)) +1

Answer (score 1):

If the `width` of `#div1` is fixed at `150px` and `#div3` is dynamic, then you can use :

```
#div2 {
    width : calc(100% - 150px);
}
```

And if `#div1` is also dynamic, then you need to use JS.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/calc - not compatibile with IE8 and android browser, is there any other way ? thanks for the answer